# Flowplayer wmode="transparent" issue

Tags: flash, flowplayer, wmode

I need to add '`<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />`' tag into FlowPlayer's `<object>` tag.

I tried the setup below:

```
$f("dvVideo", "/js/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.18.swf", { wmode: 'transparent'} .......);
```

But wmode gets added into flashparams section and it has no effect at all.

I wanted to write the object tag directly into page myself with a proper wmode tag in it. But flow player examples show static files only.

How can I play a RTMP stream with the way below:

```
<object id="flowplayer" width="300" height="200" 
    data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash">

    <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="flashvars"
        value='config={"clip":"http://stream.flowplayer.org/N8inpasadena-Flowers457.flv"}' />
</object>
```